# Copy/Cut and Paste from VIM inside Terminal

Tags: terminal, mac, ssh, vi

I am able to copy/cut and paste from the terminal using the mac clipboard.

However, when I am inside VIM, over SSH, this feature doesn't seem to work. The options are greyed out.

Copy Special is available, but I am not sure how to use it.

Is there a trick that I am missing?

Comment: I think this post would make more sense on Stack Overflow, as it isn’t necessarily Apple specific. Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/a/11489440/4722345

Comment: @JBallin No this is mac related. Terminal.app actions has no idea what is running in it